# Skipped test is not logged as Skipped in ExtentReport4

Tags: java, selenium, testing, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I got 2 tests: `addNewVideo` and `deleteRecentVideo` where the second one depends on first one. After first fails, second gets ignored and it's not running. After opening my Extent Report, it looks like this:
[image]

I'm expecting to have 2 tests - 1 failed, 1 skipped, but it's not showing properly on the report.

`ExtentListener.class`

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.*;
import org.testng.*;
import java.util.*;
import static constants.FileResources.REPORT_DIR;

public class ExtentListener implements ITestListener {

    private static Date d = new Date();
    private static String fileName = String.format("%s%s%s%s", d.toString().replaceAll("[: ]", "_"), "_", System.getenv("env"), ".html");
    private static ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.createInstance(REPORT_DIR + fileName);
    public static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> testReport = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        ExtentTest test = extent.createTest(result.getTestClass().getName() + "." + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        test.assignCategory(result.getTestClass().getName());
        testReport.set(test);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        String logText = methodName + " PASSED";
        Markup m = MarkupHelper.createLabel(logText, ExtentColor.GREEN);
        testReport.get().pass(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        String excepionMessage = Arrays.toString(result.getThrowable().getStackTrace());
        testReport.get().fail("<details>" + "<summary>" + "<b>" + "<font color=" + "red>" + "Exception occured: Expand to check details"
                + "</font>" + "</b >" + "</summary>" + excepionMessage.replaceAll(",", "<br>") + "</details>" + " \n");
        String failureLog = methodName + " FAILED";
        Markup m = MarkupHelper.createLabel(failureLog, ExtentColor.RED);
        testReport.get().log(Status.FAIL, m);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        String logText = "<b>" + methodName + " SKIPPED" + "</b>";
        Markup m = MarkupHelper.createLabel(logText, ExtentColor.ORANGE);
        testReport.get().skip(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        if (extent != null) {
            extent.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing `IInvokedMethodListener` but no success. 
Is there any way to show skipped tests properly on ExtentReport4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `IInvokeMethodListener2` once again, but it's just a workaround.

If method from `dependsOnMethods` failed, the test method was not executed at all, therefore it was not logged as `skipped`. My solution is to tag dependant methods as `description` and check before invocation if it contains any failed method from test class.

```
public class MethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener2 {

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context) {

        List<String> failed = context
                        .getFailedTests()
                        .getAllMethods()
                        .stream()
                        .map(ITestNGMethod::getMethodName)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        boolean isSkippable = false;
        if (failed.size() > 0 && method.getTestMethod().getDescription() != null) {
            List<String> methodNames = Arrays.asList(method.getTestMethod().getDescription().split(";"));
            isSkippable = failed
                            .stream()
                            .anyMatch(methodNames::contains);
        }


        if (isSkippable) {
            throw new SkipException("Skipping " + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

    }
}
```

```
@Listeners({MethodListener.class, ExtentListener.class})
public class SampleTest extends TestsBase {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void pass() {
        System.out.println("pass");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void fail1() {
        System.out.println("fail1");
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void fail2() {
        System.out.println("fail2");
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void fail3() {
        System.out.println("fail3");
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void fail4() {
        System.out.println("fail4");
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Test(priority = 6, description = "pass;fail2")
    public void skip1() {
        System.out.println("skip1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 7, description = "pass;fail3")
    public void skip2() {
        System.out.println("skip2");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Guys I also faced this issue and below code worked for me.
Define the testListener like this and then call this testListener class in your Baseclass by using @listeners(TestListeners.class) before Baseclass starts.

**Note** : I have used Spark Extentreport

public class TestListeners implements ITestListener {

@override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

```
Baseclass.extenttest = Baseclass.extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getDescription()).assignCategory("SkipedTest");
Baseclass.extenttest .log(Status.SKIP, result.getThrowable());
Baseclass.extenttest .log(Status.SKIP, result.getMethod().getDescription());
Baseclass.extenttest .log(Status.SKIP,  MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName(), ExtentColor.YELLOW));
Baseclass.extent.flush();
```

}
}

In your test class define @Test like below

@Test(description = "Test Case name", dependsOnMethods = { "Name of method on which it depends" })

[image]